# Deploying ruby app to cloud foundry, rubygems failure

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, cloud-foundry

I am a newbie to ruby. I am deploying a ruby app which reads bug id from slack, sends request to jira and sends response to slack back with bug details.
Having an issue deploying this application to cloud foundry. I am using,
cloud foundry build pack version: 1.8.25
bundler 2.1.4
ruby 2.7.0
rubygems 3.1.4.

I have a proc file which has command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT`, when I do cf push, I am getting below error:

```
 OUT Creating build for app with guid 
   2020-10-06T23:06:57.72-0400 [API/2] OUT Updated app with guid  ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
   2020-10-06T23:06:58.00-0400 [STG/0] OUT Cell  creating container for instance 
   2020-10-06T23:06:58.38-0400 [STG/0] OUT Cell successfully created container for instance 
   2020-10-06T23:06:58.70-0400 [STG/0] OUT Downloading app package...
   2020-10-06T23:06:58.75-0400 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded app package (869K)
   2020-10-06T23:07:01.25-0400 [STG/0] OUT -----> Download go 1.12.4
   2020-10-06T23:07:12.96-0400 [STG/0] OUT /tmp/buildpackdownloads/234werwrwr9c73796ddef6bc0d ~
   2020-10-06T23:07:12.96-0400 [STG/0] OUT -----> Running go build supply
   2020-10-06T23:07:15.23-0400 [STG/0] OUT ~
   2020-10-06T23:07:15.23-0400 [STG/0] OUT -----> Ruby Buildpack version 1.8.25
   2020-10-06T23:07:15.23-0400 [STG/0] OUT -----> Supplying Ruby
   2020-10-06T23:07:15.24-0400 [STG/0] OUT -----> Installing bundler 2.1.4
   2020-10-06T23:07:15.24-0400 [STG/0] OUT        Download [https://url/dependencies/bundler/bundler-2.1.4-any-stack-df7bed89.tgz]
   2020-10-06T23:07:16.64-0400 [STG/0] OUT -----> Installing ruby 2.7.0
   2020-10-06T23:07:16.64-0400 [STG/0] OUT        Download [https:/URL/dependencies/ruby/ruby-2.7.0-linux-x64-cflinuxfs3-68cd2bae.tgz]
   2020-10-06T23:07:19.08-0400 [STG/0] OUT        **WARNING** A newer version of ruby is available in this buildpack. Please adjust your app to use version 2.7.1 instead of version 2.7.0 as soon as possible. Old versions of ruby are only provided to assist in migrating to newer versions.
   2020-10-06T23:07:21.18-0400 [STG/0] OUT -----> Update rubygems from 3.1.2 to 3.1.4
   2020-10-06T23:07:21.18-0400 [STG/0] OUT -----> Installing rubygems 3.1.4
   2020-10-06T23:07:21.18-0400 [STG/0] OUT        Download [https://URL/dependencies/rubygems/rubygems_3.1.4_linux_noarch_any-stack_b59c5e57.tgz]
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /tmp/contents329128731/deps/0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so) - /tmp/contents329128731/deps/0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/contents329128731/deps/0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:2430:in `to_ruby'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/commands/setup_command.rb:401:in `install_default_bundler_gem'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/commands/setup_command.rb:174:in `execute'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/command.rb:325:in `invoke_with_build_args'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:178:in `process_args'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:148:in `run'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:59:in `run'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR  from setup.rb:41:in `<main>'
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] OUT        **ERROR** 
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] OUT        **ERROR** Unable to update rubygems: Could not install rubygems: exit status 1
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.42-0400 [STG/0] ERR Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 15
   2020-10-06T23:07:22.44-0400 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 223
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

While running "bundle install" trying to install gems, this failure is occurring.

Comment: What stack are you using? What's the output of `cf stacks`. What happens if you add `-s cflinuxfs3` to your `cf push` command or `stack: cflinuxfs3` to your manifest.yml?

Comment: When I do ```cf stacks```, I can see cflinuxfs2 & cflinuxfs3.

Comment: Hai @DanielMikusa, Container started now, but the ruby app did not start. I am closing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear from the information presented, but this error:

> 2020-10-06T23:07:22.40-0400 [STG/0] ERR /tmp/rubygems270167546/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: version` OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /tmp/contents329128731/deps/0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so) - /tmp/contents329128731/deps/0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)

looks like you have a buildpack that needs cflinuxfs3 being used on cflinuxfs2. The two stacks have different OpenSSL versions, with cflinuxfs3 having 1.1.1.

Switching stacks should at least allow you to move past this error.

`cf push -s cflinuxfs3` or set `stack: cflinuxfs3` in your manifest.yml.

---

For what it's worth, at the time I write this `cflinuxfs2` is dangerously old and out of Support. If you are using a platform that is still defaulting to the `cflinuxfs2` stack or even making it available as an option, you should talk with your platform operations team about upgrading ASAP.